# React Bootstrap Responsive Mode is not working what i want

Tags: html, css, web, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I am new developer for bootstrap. I made a product but if I collapse automatically from right side or left side of chrome it works responsive like I want. But when i choose from inspect and giving an absolute width it does not look like other one. I added two photo to describe clearly. Thank you for your effort everyone.

[image: the wrong one]

---

[image: collapsed one]

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a meta tag to get responsive in chrome responsive mode
This is the meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`