# Conditional rendering to choose display setup

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-bootstrap, conditional-formatting, conditional-rendering

**UPDATE**

I found a different solution- the page "responsiveness" wasn't working.
after adding:
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`
as @adabala-rama-krishna suggest in another question it's working as I want.
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59985426/react-bootstrap-responsive-mode-is-not-working-what-i-want)

Anyhow- if someone have a solution for the syntax problem, I'll be happy to hear about it.

---

in my react app I'm trying to change the display for mobile or desktop and add column if needed:

```
      {isTabletOrMobile
        ? <br />
        : <></Col><Col></>
      }
```

Full page code: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-agnesi-2qqzk?file=/src/App.js)

(using react-bootstrap here..)

Because the closing tag is before the opening one, it's raising a syntax error.

Is there anyway around it?

A better way to do it maybe??

Thank you all!

Comment: ```<></Col><Col></>``` is what you want? Or it is ```<><Col></Col></>```

Comment: The first one. if the screen is big, it'll split the content to two columns. if not, it'll stay one.

Comment: Can you provide more code?

Comment: Here you go: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-agnesi-2qqzk?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render the column conditionally, then you have to do it this way.

```
<Row>
 {isTabletOrMobile
        ? <Col>1</Col>
        :<><Col>1 of 2</Col>
         <Col>2 of 2</Col></>
      }
</Row>
```

Also note that you have to close the last column like `<Col></Col>`

Comment: I want all content anyway, and just the splitting conditionally...

Comment: Please update the question with enough code. What you have asked can actually be done like this

Comment: ok. just updated everything. if you know what to do in this specific case, i'll be happy to hear. thanks!